# "converting" an anon function to class method with event data input

Tags: javascript

I've obtained an anonymous function that takes an event object as input as well as another input like so:

```js
    // define a state toggle function
    const toggleDrawer = (open) => (event) => {
        // quit for certain key events
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        } // if

        // set the given toggle open state
        setState(open);
    };
```

I would like to incorporate this as a method in a class, but unsure how to rewrite inputs.
I could just store the variable as a property on the object, but I would like to write it like so:

```js
/*
View-model of the Drawer view.
*/
class DrawerModel {

    // class constructor
    constructor() {

        // initialise a drawer state
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

        // store the state and set function on the object
        this.open = open;
        this.setOpen = setOpen;

    } // constructor

    // method to toggle the drawer
    toggleDrawer(open) {
        // quit for certain key events
        // TODO: how to pass event in like with the anon fnc?
        // const toggleDrawer = (open) => (event) => {...
        //if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
        //    return;
        //} // if

        // set the given toggle open state
        setState(open);
    } // toggleDrawer

} // class
```

The toggleDrawer function can be assigned as the callback for some UI component events.

I don't understand the anonymous function definition with multiple inputs "= (open) => (event) =>".

1. Could someone explain/link how that works?
2. How do I make that event data available with how I'm writing the class method?

Comment: Every `(..) => ..` is a new function. `toggleDrawer` is a function which returns a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [currying function](https://javascript.info/currying-partials). It is function which returns function. With classic syntax (not arrow syntax as your example is) you can write it like this:

```js
class DrawerModel {
  toggleDrawer(open) {
     return function(event) {
        // do your magic here
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting, this makes sense now seeing how it is added as an event callback.
thank you!